# Decomposition of a measure into series

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M(X)$ be the vector space of all complex regular Borel measures on a compact Hausdorff space $X$,$||\mu ||=|\mu|(X)$.

Suppose $\mu , \lambda_n \in M(X),n\in N^+ $,$||\lambda_n||=1$.Since Lebesgue decomposition,we obtain 
$$ \mu=h_1+g_1,h_1\ll \lambda_1,g_1 \perp \lambda_1$$
 We make a similar decomposition $g_1=h_2+g_2,h_2\ll \lambda_2,g_2 \perp \lambda_2$.By induction ,we obtain:

$$\mu=\sum^{n} _{i=1} h_i  +g_n$$

We let $n\rightarrow \infty$ and obtain a series,my question is :Does the series converges in the sense of $||\cdot||$.

I will appreciate your help.